# UPDATE FROM SELECT JOIN for unique matches

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want UPDATE FROM SELECT JOIN but only if there is exactly one match on the right side of the join. Is there an idiom for this?

I have short_name (e.g. ABC) and long_name (e.g. ABC-DEF-01). For each long name, see if there are any short names matching it (e.g. ABC in ABC-DEF-001 ). If there is *exactly one* short name that matches, update the empty short_name column with that short_name value.

I believe this does the task, but I don't think it's the *right* way to do it. Is there a **cleaner** or **faster** way? [Here's an interactive version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0d35/26) for convenience.

I'm particularly concerned about the `array_agg()`, which seems out of line with the relational idioms.

```
create table long_names (short_name varchar, long_name varchar);
insert into long_names (long_name)
values
('ABC-DEF-01'),
('ABC-DEF-02'),
('CDE-FGH-01');


create table short_names(short_name varchar);
insert into short_names(short_name)
values
('ABC'),
('DEF'),
('FGH');


UPDATE long_names
SET short_name = subquery.short_name 
FROM (
SELECT
    long_names.long_name, 
    count(short_names.short_name), 
    (array_agg(short_names.short_name))[1] AS short_name
FROM long_names 
LEFT JOIN short_names
ON long_names.long_name LIKE ('%' || short_names.short_name || '%')
GROUP BY long_names.long_name
HAVING count(DISTINCT short_names.short_name) = 1
) AS subquery
WHERE long_names.long_name = subquery.long_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
min(short_names.short_name)
```

instead of

```
(array_agg(short_names.short_name))[1]
```

but other than that I cannot think of a better way to accomplish this.